# Magento remove css or js from specific view

Tags: css, magento, layout, addition

Hi i added this to catalog.xml  layout definition:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/local.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

and this to  inside the same file:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>css</type><name>css/local.css</name></action>
```

But it doesn't remove the css from that view. It is possible, that its not the right markup to achieve this. But have no idea. Anyone can help out?

Comment: have you made shure, that your catalog.xml or some handle is is not overwritten by another extension?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try skin_css:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/local.css</name></action>
```

Answer (score 77):

Here is how to remove all the different CSS and JS in skin or js folder

```
<reference name="head">
    <!-- For a JS in the js folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>functions.js</name></action>
    <!-- For a JS in the skin folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>functions.js</name></action>
    <!-- For CSS in the skin folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/local.css</name></action>
    <!-- For CSS in the js folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>local.css</name></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Good job going above and beyond OPs question to help fellow Googlers.

Comment: Thanks @Benjam ! Magento is very difficult, and partial answers doesn't help much.